# How do you place paintings on signs in minecraft in Xbox 360 edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I want to place a painting on a sign. Please help!

Comment: How about a bit more information, and show that you've done some research on this.

Comment: Have you tried crouching?

Comment: Are you talking about placing a painting on the sides of signs to make hidden rooms?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're attempting to place a painting on a sign to create a secret room; the answer is that you can't place a painting **on** a sign.

What you can do is place the painting on a solid block next to a doorway, like this:

[image]
(Red block where the painting is placed)

The random generation of the painting counts the signs (or anything with a sideways hitbox, i.e. ladders, doors, etc.) as a solid block and allows generation over it, creating a secret doorway.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the image. In the future, please use Arqade's own image uploader rather than third-party sites, which helps avoid losing key parts of an answer to link rot.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I will be sure to do that in the future